# Find Maximum Number Index In 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, max, minimum

So I'm trying to come up with this method that will display the index of the maximum number in the 2D array. I was able to do it for a single D array, but I'm having trouble doing it for the 2D.

```
public static int findMaximumValue(int[ ][ ] a)
{
   int maxVal = a [0][0];
   int i = 0;

   for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
   {
      for(int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++)
      {
         if(a[i][j] > maxVal)
         {
            maxVal = a[i][j];
         }
      }
   }
   return(maxVal);
 }
```

***2D ARRAY***

```
public static int [][] findMaximumIndex(int[ ][ ] a)
{
   int maxVal = a[0][0];
   int [][] maxIndex = new int [1][2];
   int row = 0, col = 0; 

   for(row = 0; row < a.length; row++)
   {
      for(col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++)
      {
         if(a[row][col] > maxVal)
         {
           maxVal = a[row][col];
           maxIndex [1] [2] = a[row][col];
         }
      }
   }
   return(maxIndex); 
}
```

Comment: in 2d array you return one element but your return type is integer 2d array

Comment: maxVal = a[row][col];
           maxIndex [1] [2] = a[row][col];              you doing same thing in two steps you assign maxvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are returning a 2d int array when you want to return the index of the maxValue which will be a row index and a column index. Perhaps you want to return an array of size 2 to represent this? more info would be helpful.  Second, I'm not sure what your doing with the maxIndex 2d array. Each time you iterate through the 2d array, just comepare the maxvalue to the current element. havent got an IDE near to debug but should go something like this:

```
  public static int[] findMaximumIndex(int[ ][ ] a)
{
    int maxVal = -99999
    int[] answerArray = new int[2];
    for(int row = 0; row < a.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++)
        {
            if(a[row][col] > maxVal)
            {
                maxVal = a[row][col];
                answerArray[0] = row;
                answerArray[1] = col;
            }
        }
    }
    return answerArray;
}
```

here answerArray[0] will have the row index for the max element and answerArray[1] will have the column index for the max element

Comment: That will give me the maximum value, but I'am trying to output the index of the maximum value in the 2D array.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, there will be two indexes since you have rows and columns. so do you want to print out the row and col? or you can throw them in an array of size 2 you can return but that would be very strange

Comment: Thats what I'am trying to do, I want to return it rather than print out. I'm just not sure how to do it exactly.

Comment: answer updated again. Is this what youre looking for?

Comment: I don't think `maxVal` would be necessary.

Comment: @Edward Lavaire if you found this helpful, make sure to upvote/accept so others can see